# How do I 'check' a radio button value using django RadioSelect widget

Tags: python, django

In HTML you can easily do this by using the word 'checked' next to a radio button input field.

How do you do this in django using ModelForm?

I have 2 choices for my radio button code 'Regular Service' and 'Premium Service'. I would like 'Regular Service' to automatically be checked.

Here are the relevant parts of my forms.py

```
CHOICES = (
    (1,'Regular Service'),
    (0,'Premium Service')
)

class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
     regular_service = forms.ChoiceField(required = True, choices = CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class' : 'Radio'}), initial={'regular_service':'Regular Service'})
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should set initial to 1, which is the key of the choice you want to be checked.

```
class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    regular_service = forms.ChoiceField(required = True, choices = CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class' : 'Radio'}), initial=1)
```